# Numerical Analysis ODE's

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to solve this problem, but am having some trouble.

The ODE $u''=\cfrac{u'}t - 4t^2u$ has the solution $u(t)=\sin(t^2)+\cos(t^2)$.

I want to plot the exact solution over the interval $[1,20]$. Can someone help me figure out this exact solution and how to go about solving it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it want me to just plot u(t)?

Comment: It depends on what "it" is. You have the exact solution -- plotting it should not be so difficult.

Comment: [$u(t)=\sin(t^2)+\cos(t^2)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u(t)%3D%5Csin(t%5E2)%2B%5Ccos(t%5E2))